# How to assign the array key a value, when the key name is itself a variable

Tags: javascript, hash, arrays, key

How do I identify an item in a hash array if the key of the array is only known within a variable? For example:

```
var key = "myKey";
var array = {myKey: 1, anotherKey: 2};
alert(array.key);
```

Also, how would I assign a value to that key, having identified it with the variable?

This is, of course, assuming that I must use the variable key to identify which item in the array to alert.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have confused an object literal for an array.  An array always, until elements are forcefully removed, has a fixed key made of integers that increment by 1 starting at 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there:-

```
var array = {myKey: 1, anotherKey: 2};
```

- is not an Array. It is a native `Object` object with two properties.

An ECMAScript `Array` is also an object, though a more specialized object type, having a `length` property, among other things.

To answer your question, you can use the square bracket property access operators. Renaming your variable to `myObj`, that would be `myObj[ key ]`, where `key` is an identifier that resolves to a value that is converted to a string.

For a brief explanation, see:
[How do I access a property of an object using a string?](http://jibbering.com/faq/#propertyAccessAgain).

For more detail, see
[ECMA-262-3 in detail. Chapter 7.2. OOP: ECMAScript implementation](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-7-2-oop-ecmascript-implementation/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
alert(array[key]);
```

That is the standard syntax for what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the key like:

```
alert(array[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

With traditional array notation:

```
alert(array[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Access it just like you would an index in an array. For the example you gave: `alert(array[key]);`